# How do you connect power between buildings in Drake Hollow?

Tags: drake-hollow

I just leveled up to town level 3 and unlocked the treadmill and the advanced curio workbench. After building both, I’m given a prompt when attempting to interact with the advanced curio workshop saying that it needs power. When attempting to interact with the treadmill, I start walking on it. There’s no prompt about how to connect the two buildings to supply power between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Xbox All you have to do is click the inspect button and hold x on the advanced curio workshop. It will give you a prompt to connect power and you run the power line to the treadmill!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was an inspect button. For everyone's info, it's right thumbstick, indicated at bottom right. You'll need to press it again later to toggle back out of inspect mode.